# Why this 9 patch splash screen is not working?

Tags: android, delphi, android-drawable, android-styles, nine-patch

I'm under Delphi (I don't know if it matters) and I can't understand. I define my 9 patch splash screen like below (original size is 28*28px) :

[image: splash design]

But when I run (on an xhdpi device) I get this (the background of the status bar is not aligned):

[image: result]

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff2b2e38</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: in which folder did you put the nine-patch image

Comment: i put the nine patch in different folder with good size (MDPI - HDPI - XHDPI - XXHDPI - XXXHDPI). For this example i put it only in xhdpi but it's change nothing

Comment: What exactly is the issue @loki?

Comment: Please define "Not Working". You should understand by now that this is *never* a valid problem statement.

Comment: @JerryDodge : i can't believe, you don't see the problem? i even do a draw! what else i can do ? look the background of the status bar that is not aligned now ...

Comment: @Zippy: seriously you don't see? like i say to jerry, look the background of the status bar that is not aligned now ...

Comment: @loki: Seeing is not the problem. Give a useful problem description, i.e. what you expect to get and what you actually get. "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: How am I supposed to know that's your problem? Sure, I see it, but for all I know, perhaps you want it to look like that. If my car had a scratch in the hood, and I took it to the mechanic and told them "It's not working, please fix it." Do you think they would know that I want them to fix the scratch?

Comment: @loki I could see the problem, even before the question edit. No clue as to what the answer is

Comment: @ everyone, ok i understand .. so i updaded the question to make more clear where the problem is. After all, it's true that the comment here are for this, ask for clarification ... @DaveNottage yea it's really (really) strange this problem ! look like the background of the status bar is draw AFTER the 9 patch background :( for me look like more a bug in android and not delphi, because i can't see what delphi can do at this very early stage ... but on other way if it's was on android strange that i m the only one to meet this :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue purely on Android side using Android Studio. What is your device API?

Comment: Thanks @DalijaPrasnikar. this bug make make me crazy, the only think i changed is to set in the AndroidManifest.template.xml android:targetSdkVersion="22" instead of android:targetSdkVersion="15"

after like i say in the question i use android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar and that all ... can't understand :(

Comment: the only way out i found (for device > api 21, else not work) is to set in xml the background of the status bar to be blue :(

Comment: What happens if you use regular image instead of 9 patch?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar : with regular image it's ok, it's deformed of course to fit all the background, but ok.

Comment: @loki I guess you should fill another bug report

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar : hmm you think it's connected to Delphi? how can Delphi interfere at a so early stage ?

Comment: I seriously don't know, but I cannot reproduce it with Android Studio. Maybe you could try - it should not be that hard. After all, you have actual 9 patch image and actual device. If Android Studio produces properly working app, then you will know for sure Delphi is the culprit.

Comment: BTW, I would also try with different 9 patch images.

Comment: i will try with android studio, i must understand where the problem is ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try some implementation other than 9-patch drawable? Here's a splash screen drawable resource I use in one of my project, a solid background with logo at the center.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/your_app_theme"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/your_logo"/>
</item>
```

I'm not sure which splash screen design you're trying to reach. For more information, you can provide a design mock-up, sketching or something.